# What's the difference between new String(byte[]) and DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byte[])?

Tags: java, base64

I need to pass base64 encoded data into xml as a string value. I noticed that code below prints different string representation. Which one is correct and why?

```
    String example = "Hello universe!";
    byte[] base64data = Base64.encodeBase64(example.getBytes());
    System.out.println(new String(base64data));
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(base64data));

    System.out.println(new String(Base64.decodeBase64(base64data), "UTF-8"));
```

And what I get as a result:

```
SGVsbG8gdW5pdmVyc2Uh
U0dWc2JHOGdkVzVwZG1WeWMyVWg=
Hello universe!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`U0dWc2JHOGdkVzVwZG1WeWMyVWg=` decoded is `SGVsbG8gdW5pdmVyc2Uh` which is `Hello universe!` encoded. So you did the encoding twice.

There is no difference. You are using the API the wrong way. Don't encode the already encoded data again.

Comment: You're right. The name of method misleaded me. If it was printAsBase64Binary or encodeBase64Binary there wouldn't be any question :) And there IS difference. First one just prints bytes but second encodes and prints bytes